# Keep vim cursor position in document fixed when typing search expression

Tags: search

I recently upgraded vim for the first time in 5 years.  Now, when I type in a search expression, the cursor in the buffer changes position with each key stroke to highlight a potential match.  I want to disable this because it prevents me from using `<Ctrl-r><Ctrl-w>` to yank in the word where I positioned the cursor just before beginning a search.

What is the option for disabling the movement of the cursor when typing in a search expression?

Comment: are you not using a `.vimrc` file? Than Vim would start reading the defaults.vim (`:h defaults.vim`, for how to disable loading it). Otherwise, Vim shouldn't mysteriously have set it, if it didn't do it before

Comment: I'm reading my own vimrc file, the result of decades of evolution.  It's the same vimrc file as before I upgraded vim.  I don't set `incsearch` or `is` in it.  But there have been many changes since the upgrade.  I haven't tracked them all down.  For example, I find that now I have to explicitly set `scrolloff` to zero, which used to be default.  Also had to track down how to avoid automatic indentations that are specific to the source code language of the file being editted.  The `incsearch` option is just one of many things that seem to have different defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the right search phrase.  Hoping that this will save someone an afternoon:

From [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/e2ho90/any_ways_to_disable_jumping_when_searching_with), the option is `incsearch`.  To disable it, I do `:set noincsearch`.

Comment: Or, more precisely, `set noincsearch` to disable it, right?

Comment: Yes!  Thanks for prompting me to clarify that.